# Ternary operator in array initalization

Tags: c, c99

Is using the tenary operator within array initalization with constants valid C99?

```
uint8_t foo[] = {bar? 9U:20U};
```

Comment: I have a feeling that @coderredoc is having a decent answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you may. Starting from the grammar production for an initalizer:

**6.7.8 Initialization**

> ```
> initializer:
>        assignment-expression
>        { initializer-list }
>        { initializer-list , }
> initializer-list:
>        designation(optional) initializer
>        initializer-list , designation(optional) initializer
> ```

The only relevant (in my opinion) constraint on the initializer in that section is that it must be a constant expression for objects with static storage duration:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Following it onward to the production of `assignment-expression`, we see that

**6.5.16 Assignment operators**

> ```
> assignment-expression:
>         conditional-expression
>         unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
> ```

A conditional expression is a valid assignment expression as well. So it may appear as an initializer in an initializer list. The only thing left to check is that it can be a valid constant expression for objects with static storage duration.

**6.6 Constant expressions**

> ```
> constant-expression:
>          conditional-expression
> ```

With the following constraint and semantic paragraphs:

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.
>
> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers.
>   Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
>   following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for an object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

So all of the above makes for the following valid program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BAR 1

uint8_t foo[] = {BAR ? 9U:20U};

int main(void) {
   int bar = rand();
   uint8_t foo[] = {bar ? 9U:20U};
}
```

Furthermore, for objects with automatic storage duration, you aren't limited to constant expressions as the two sub-expressions of the conditional expression. They can refer to any object in scope as well.

Comment: Does the initalizer has to be compile-time evaluable? Referring to @Carl Norum

Comment: @user259819 - Only for objects with static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

No. From `clang`:

```
example.c:4:15: warning: initializer for aggregate is not a compile-time
      constant [-Wc99-extensions]
        int foo[] = {bar? 9U:20U};
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Strange, why can't I reproduce?

Comment: What's the storage duration of `foo`? What's `bar` in your example? What does a warning message without the [mcve] which produces it prove?